# Are movie/ TV show success/ failure story discussions allowed?

Tags: discussion, support, scope

Are movie/ TV show success/ failure story discussions allowed?

Means questions like -

- Why is this film flop?
- Reasons for success/ failure of a film/ TV show?
- How much income or loss through a film/ TV show cost to the producers, directors or actors?

Answer (score 5):

This is something that has been experimented with before.

Due to the opinionated nature of films, it is hard to be objective in analysis of why a movie flopped at the box office or is considered the worst of its time.

When asking a question like this, you have to ask yourself if it can be answered objectively and also state what you are looking for in an objective manner.

For instance, if no one liked Adventure Time because they just don't like it, that is all subjective and not a fit for this site.

But, if the same question was but was phrased in a way asking for objective views of why it was not a successful show, then you would get figured like ratings, cost per episode vs return from advertisement, etc.

Essentially, if a question like this is asked, make it clear the answers must contain objective views as subjective gets closed as *Not Constructive* due to the discussion occurring.

---

Ask for objective figures, average rating, sales figures for both theatre and dvd/digital, neilson ratings for tv shows, etc.

Comment: Any question which gives birth to opinions is discouraged.

Comment: So what should be etiquette followed if this type of question to be asked and it is not a subjective question?

Comment: Ask for objective figures, average rating, sales figures for both theatre and dvd/digital, neilson ratings for tv shows, etc.

Comment: @TylerShads: Please include your above response in your answer as whole. It is most important point.

Answer (score 0):

I think these should be off-topic.  They almost always boil down to one thing: money.  The ratings weren't high enough to make the show profitable.  Or the box office returns didn't exceed the film's budget.  Some small number of these will be interesting cases where there was some behind-the-scenes conflict or issue that resulted in the cancellation/flop.  I'm loathe to encourages an endless stream of people asking about their pet favorite work and why it didn't run for 10 seasons or spawn a full trilogy when the majority of the time it'll boil down to money.